# How to add TestUnit / Minitest to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I did a:

```
--skip-test-unit
```

When installing rails 4, and now I want to use testunit / minitest (not sure which one is default in rails 4.1?)

So how do I re-add testunit / minitest to rails?

Comment: while creating rails new application you passed --no-skip-test-unit which means do not skip Test::Unit files.Check your Rails Dir, you will find test folder with sub-folders in it.

Comment: Oops I mean I did --skip-test-unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default rake command for this but the simplest workaround is generate new rails application with test

```
rails new test1
```

now copy the test folder from test1 to your repository

```
cp -r test ../your_repository_name
```

open config/application.rb

uncomment  `require "rails/test_unit/railtie"`

now when you will generate model or controller in you application, then it will generate test files also.

For previous model and controller you can use

```
rails generate test_unit:controller ControllerName
rails generate test_unit:model ModelName
```

By default Rails 4.1 is using minitest (5.3.3)